# Using VBA to check if below cell is empty

Tags: excel, vba

How do I use VBA in Excel to check if a below cell is empty or not?
I want to sum all values in a specific range, but only, if the below cell is not empty.

Is that somehow possible with VBA or any other way?

Example:

```
4 2 3 2 1
2   3 1
```

Sum would be: 4 + 3 + 2 = 9.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend a Formula for this

**FORMULA**

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A1:E1)*(A2:E2<>""))
```

SNAPSHOT

[image]

If you still want VBA then

**VBA**

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim Cl As Range
    Dim tot As Long

    Set rng = Range("A1:F1")

    For Each Cl In rng
        If Len(Trim(Cl.Offset(1))) <> 0 Then tot = tot + Cl.Value
    Next

    Debug.Print tot
End Sub
```

In fact you can have many versions in VBA. You can evaluate the above formula as well. For example

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Debug.Print Evaluate("=SUMPRODUCT((A1:E1)*(A2:E2<>""""))")
End Sub
```

Comment: @Siddarth Rout, very nice approach.

Comment: @Cherrun: "<>" stands for `Not Equal To`. So I am simply taking cells into account which are not empty in the range A2:E2.

Comment: @Siddharth Rout I agree, clever use of SumProduct but I think you have misunderstood cherrun's question about "<>". `A2:E2<>""` returns True or False for each column. You are then using `True` or `False` as an integer. Excel treats True as 1 and False as 0. So the SumProduct is `4*True + 2*False + 3*True + 2*True + 1*False` = `4*1 + 2*0 + 3*1 + 2*1 + 1*0` = `9`. Clever but, unless you know that booleans are implicitly converted to integers, incomprehensible.

Comment: @TonyDallimore: Ah! In that case I misunderstood the question :)

Comment: @Siddharth Rout. I think your answers are beautifully presented, you display a depth of knowledge I will never aspire to and where do you find the time to answer so many questions but sometimes I suspect you forget how far ahead of the rest of us you are.  However, even if I am correct about cherrun's true question, keep up the good work; your answers are a pleasure to read.

Comment: @Tony Dallimore and Sidd
Thank you both for your answers! In fact I didn't know that <> meant not equal, and therefore didn't know that it was converted to integers as well. Thanks you both!

Comment: +1 Another good answer.  Agree with @TonyDallimore. Your answers are a pleasure to read. Keep up the good work. :)

Answer (score 16):

Try this simple code

```
If IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0)) Then
'your code here
End If
```

Answer (score 2):

I've had some problems using just 'IsEmpty' when the data is exported from other databases. This is the function I've developed:

```
Function IsVacant(TheVar As Variant) As Boolean
  'LeandraG 2010

  IsVacant = False

  If IsEmpty(TheVar) Then IsVacant = True
  If Trim(TheVar) = "" Then IsVacant = True
  If Trim(TheVar) = "'" Then IsVacant = True


End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who are desperate: sometimes an Excel cell seems empty, but upon inspection may contain something invisible, such as a space character. And then all those IsEmpty and IsNull functions won't help you.