# vba: Figure out if a changing range is blank

Tags: excel, vba

I have two spreadsheets, one contains programs and one projects. I use `D` loops to look at projects, within programs, within countries. I am trying to figure out if a set of cells for each project is blank. I have tried a few things. In the case below `sustTrue` should stay at `0` if `rangeVar` is blank for all the projects, but it does not. Please help!

```
Sub NO_Sheet()

Sheets("Program_FINAL").Select
Range("C2").Select ' C column is country 
Dim IndicatorLineIterator
Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell) ' loop until country is blank
      IndicatorLineIterator = 61
      Dim PRGNum
      PRGNum = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -2).Value ' Identify the program number

      Sheets("Project_FINAL").Select
      Range("A2").Select ' A column is the project number

      Dim rangeVar, sustTrue
      sustTrue = 0
      Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell) ; loop until Project number is blank

            If PRJNum = ActiveCell.Value Then

                'rangeVar = ("O" & ActiveCell.Row & ":S" & ActiveCell.Row)
                rangeVar = Range(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 14) & ":" & ActiveCell.Offset(0, 17))
                If Not IsEmpty(rangeVar) Then
                    sustTrue = sustTrue + 1
                    MsgBox (sustTrue)
                End If

            End If
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        Loop
End If

'Sheets(SheetADPName).Range("M16").Value = sustTrue

Sheets("Program_FINAL").Select
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Loop


End Sub
```

Comment: Are there formulas in rangeVar?

Comment: Further, you can't reliably use the `IsEmpty` on a range array, only a single cell or other simple data type.

Answer (score 0):

Your `rangeVar` is not a range object.

Strongly type your variables:

```
Dim rangeVar as Range
Dim sustTrue as Long 'Or As Integer
Dim cl as Range
```

Then use the `Set` keyword to assign object variables and instead of concatenating, we can just list the two cells separated by a comma, and this will create the range:

```
Set rangeVar = Range(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 14), ActiveCell.Offset(0, 17))
```

Further, you can't reliably use the `IsEmpty` on a range array, only a single cell or other simple data type.  You can get around this by iterating the range:

```
For each cl in rangeVar.Cells
    If Not IsEmpty(cl.Value) Then
        sustTrue = sustTrue + 1

    End If
Next
MsgBox (sustTrue)
```

The `IsEmpty` function may not be a foolproof way to do this check. But the rest of the logic above should help. Let me know if you have trouble with the `IsEmpty` part.

Another alternative would be to simply subtract the number of blanks from the total number of cells in that range (again, may not be 100% reliable if the cells aren't "truly" blank...)...

```
sustTrue = rangeVar.Cells.Count - rangeVar.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Cells.Count
```

Comment: I tried this and it gives me run time error 1004 "Metrhod 'Range; of object '_global' failed" on the set rangeVar line

Comment: My mistake, do this instead: `Set rangeVar = Range(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 14), ActiveCell.Offset(0, 17))`

Answer (score 0):

I kept working on it and the following worked for me. There is probably a more streamlined way to do this, but this works!

```
                If Not ActiveCell.Offset(0, 14) = "" Or Not ActiveCell.Offset(0, 15) = "" Or Not ActiveCell.Offset(0, 16) = "" Or Not ActiveCell.Offset(0, 17) = "" Then
                    sustTrue = sustTrue + 1
                    MsgBox (sustTrue)
                End If
```

Answer (score -2):

`RangeVar` is a range object. You would need to do `Isempty(RangeVar.Value)`

I think this has been answered already here: [Using VBA to check if below cell is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10263644/using-vba-to-check-if-below-cell-is-empty)

Comment: `RangeVar` is **not** an object in OP's code, even if that is the intention.

Comment: Ok, so rangevar should be in the form of "O#:S#" according to the commented out section.  Isempty(Range(rangevar).value) then?