# Type mismatch error when types are clearly uniform

Tags: excel, vba

Below is my code
When the msg box runs it has no problem producing the string, when it selects said cell it is in text format.

```
Dim LastRow As Long, FirstRow As Long
Dim Row As Long

With ActiveSheet
    Dim M, S As String
    M = "M"
    S = "S"
    'Define First and Last Rows
    FirstRow = 1
    LastRow = .UsedRange.Rows(.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row
    
    'Loop Through Rows (Bottom to Top)
    For Row = LastRow To FirstRow Step -1
    .Range("I" & Row).Select
    MsgBox ("A" & .Range("I" & Row).Value)
        If .Range("I" & Row).Value = Null Then
            
        ElseIf .Range("I" & Row).Value2 = M Or S Then       'Type mismatch here
            .Range("I" & Row).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next Row
End With
```

I am trying to remove every row with an s or m in column I

Comment: It should be `.Range("I" & Row).Value2 = M Or .Range("I" & Row).Value2 = S`

Comment: Consider removing `If .Range("I" & Row).Value = Null Then`.

Comment: God bless your soul

Comment: Btw `Dim M, S As String` ---> `Dim M As String, S As String`

Comment: How do i mark this as answered?

Comment: I can't remove the if null thing it doesnt like the empty values

Comment: Normally [one uses `IsEmpty`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10263644/using-vba-to-check-if-below-cell-is-empty) to test if a cell is empty. Also, you don't need to (actually can't) mark this as answered, since it has been closed as a duplicate. Also, comparing an empty cell's `.Value2` to "M" or to "S" does not throw an error. For verification: select an empty cell and type `? ActiveCell.Value2 = "M"` in the Immediate Window and hit Enter.