# Test three non-contiguous ranges to determine if all cells are empty

Tags: excel, vba

I need to check three non-contiguous ranges to determine if they have been populated with dates.
If not, return a message informing the user.

What I have debugs with

> run-time error '424': Object required

at `"If Range("T2")...`

```vb
Sub DateChecker()

Dim tlastRow As Long
Dim ulastRow As Long
Dim wlastRow As Long

tlastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
ulastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
wlastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

If Range("T2" & tlastRow) Is Empty And Range("U2" & ulastRow) Is Empty And Range("W2" & wlastRow) Is Empty Then GoTo NoDates
NoDates:
MsgBox "Dates have not been populated", vbExclamation
Exit Sub

End Sub
```

Comment: Go with `If Len(Range("T" & tlastRow)) = 0` instead (you could ad Trim() but idk if that's what you're going for exactly) or check out [this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10263644/using-vba-to-check-if-below-cell-is-empty). You can't just say "Empty". `T2 & tlastRow` with tlastRow being for example 100 would give you the value of T2100 btw ;)

Comment: you need to check the whole range, so instead of `Range("T2" & tlastRow)` you'll need `Range("T2:T" & tlastRow)`. Same for the rest of ranges

Comment: Do you want to check if **any** cells between the first and last rows in the 3 columns are empty ?

Comment: `Is Empty` should be used only for objects. Try `If Range("T2" & tlastRow).value = ""`. Now, do you want checking if **any of the respective cells is empty**? If so, you should use `Or` instead of `And`. Then, as asked above, do you want checking only the last row of each column of these three?

Comment: May thanks to everyone for your comments and for helping me understand where I was going wrong. A solution has now been posted by Black Cat. Thanks again, TE :)

Comment: Is it intentional to check the last row of column A (1) for each?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is Empty is not used in VBA in this context. Furthermore IsEmpty function cannot be used for ranges with more than one cell.

Try to use `WorksheetFunction.Counta` function sg. like this

```
If WorksheetFunction.Counta(Range("T2:T" & tlastRow))=0 And _ 
WorksheetFunction.Counta(Range("U2:U" & ulastRow))=0 And _ 
WorksheetFunction.Counta(Range("W2:W" & wlastRow))=0 Then
    MsgBox "Dates have not been populated", vbExclamation
End If


End Sub
```

You will get the message only if all of the ranges are totally empty.

Comment: Many thanks for your help and guidance towards the successful result - TE :)

Answer (score 3):

I'd probably suggest doing something like this:

```
Sub DateChecker()

    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim rngT As Range, rngU As Range, rngW As Range
    
    With ActiveSheet
    
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        
        Set rngT = .Range("T2:T" & lastRow)
        Set rngU = .Range("U2:U" & lastRow)
        Set rngW = .Range("W2:W" & lastRow)
        
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(rngT, rngU, rngW) = 0 Then
            MsgBox "Dates have not been populated", vbExclamation
        End If
    
    End With

End Sub
```

Note: I replaced your three lastRow variables with just one, as each contained the same value as were all reading column A. Any easy change to undo if you want to.

Comment: Although, you don't really need to use Union in this case.

Comment: Quite right, I forgot COUNTA handles multiple ranges. I shall remove it.

Comment: Many thanks - this solution worked perfectly as well. :)